# Classification with Integers and Types

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Let's say we have the following dataset

```
Label  |        Features          |  
-----------------------------------
Age    | Size | Weight | shoeSize |
20     | 180  | 80     | 42       |
40     | 173  | 56     | 38       |
```

as i know features in machine learning should be normalized and the ones mentioned above can be normalized really good. but what if i want to extend the feature list for for example the following features

```
| Gender | Ethnicity |
| 0      | 1         |
| 1      | 2         |
| 0      | 3         |
| 0      | 2         |
```

where the Gender values 0 and 1 are for female and male. and the Ethnicity values 1, 2 and 3 are for asian, hispanic and european. since these values reference types i am note sure if they can be normalized.

if they can not be normalized how can i handle mixing values like the size with types like the enthnicity.

Comment: Notice that normalization is not required always by definition, and it depends on the model to be used; tree-based models, for example, do not require it. In any case, this is a methodology question and not a programming one, and it would be more appropriate for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.